# WordPress No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am pulling posts from one WordPress website to another. Both websites are on same server. For pulling posts i am using **jQuery.ajax** with Rest API. But i am getting error message in console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.website1.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?tags=4,198&per_page=24&offset=1&_embed' from origin 'https://website2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

For this i have added following header

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

In .htaccess of both websites. Also i have used this

```
crossDomain: true,
```

In ajax. But still having error. Any help. Please

Comment: Can you inspect the headers of the response (of jQuery.ajax) and see `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is there?

Comment: I think the following link can help you.
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr**

Answer (score 0):

Just add below lines to .htaccess file and we should be good.

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c="">
   SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: Not working. I have change this line
SetEnvIf Origin "^(.*\.domain\.com)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
with my domain. But still not working.